# What is the jeu de mots of "Encorutilfaluquejelesus" ?

Tags: jeux-de-mots

I see *encore utile fallu que je* but I can't really make much sense of that, nor can I get anything out of *lesus*. Les "us"? Le "sus"? *Les use* ?

*Still useful needed that I use them*... ?

This is a Roman prefect's name in Astérix, of course.

Comment: Side note, is it jeu de mots or jeux de mots? The dictionary has it as *jeu* but the site tag is *jeux*. Is this just singular vs plural, as in one or more than one play on words? It's a little odd just because in English it's normally singular only,  "plays on words" would generally be replaced by "wordplay."

Comment: Except for the spelling of "susse" at the end, I'd guess, without really knowing what any of it means, that it's a phonetic rendition of ["Encore eût-il fallu que je le susse"](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/encore-e%C3%BBt-il-fallu-que-je-le-susse.739803/).

Comment: Ah ha! There's no question, you're right. But according to your link there's a double entendre there....what is it? I do not see it. Quote: *You should also know that such an expression is widely used among "erudite" circles because of its delightful double-entendre.*

Comment: The *double-entendre* is *je le susse* (subjunctive imperfect of *savoir*) which is pronounced exactly the same as *je le suce* (indicative present of *sucer*).

Comment: @jlliagre i was under the impression imperfect subjunctive was literary only. Is that not so?

Comment: Definitely literary but this very sentence is widely known by French people, even those not in "erudite circles", because of the pun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The full phrase is as follows:

> Encore eût-il fallu que je le susse.

Meaning roughly “Would that I had known”.
Conjugated verbs are *avoir* and *savoir* in subjunctive imperfect form (*avoir* is used as an auxiliary to obtain plusqueparfait, here used as a past conditional).

*Avoir* or *être* may occasionally occur in imperfect subjuntive form in set phrases, but the use of this tense with other verbs is seldom found outside literature, which makes the utterance atypical.

Also, "susse" generally sounds funny because of the homophony with "suce", present tense for *sucer* (suck), but it's likely not the main intended effect here. It was primarily chosen in reminiscence to the latin inflection *us*.

Comment: Never underestimate the amount of jokes intended for older crowds in cartoons and comics !

Comment: I would add that nowadays usage of the subjonctive imperfect has a  pedantic connotation, often intended (for comical effect).